# When is it a good idea to return a pointer to a struct?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm learning Go, and I'm a little confused about when to use pointers. Specifically, when returning a `struct` from a function, when is it appropriate to return the struct instance itself, and when is it appropriate to return a pointer to the struct?

Example code:

```
type Car struct {
  make string
  model string
}

func Whatever() {
  var car Car

  car := Car{"honda", "civic"}

  // ...

  return car
}
```

What are the situations where I would want to return a pointer, and where I would *not* want to? Is there a good rule of thumb?

Comment: Would the same rules not apply?

Comment: nope, different rules for different languages. Every languages has it's caveats, and I personally don't know Go, so I can't speak for it, but I do know that in C, returning a pointer to an object allocated on the stack is a giant no-no.

Comment: I'm disturbed by the answers : I think the grey zone is related to performances on small objects and I see no way to estimate the fastest solution apart profiling. Is it simply faster to pass by value objects smaller than 64bits ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two things you want to keep in mind, performance and API.

How is a Car used? Is it an object which has state? Is it a large struct? Unfortunately, it is impossible to answer when I have no idea what a Car is. Truthfully, the best way is to see what others do and copy them. Eventually, you get a feeling for this sort of thing. I will now describe three examples from the standard library and explain why I think they used what they did.

1. `hash/crc32`: The [`crc32.NewIEEE()`](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/crc32/#NewIEEE) function returns a pointer type (actually, an interface, but the underlying type is a pointer). An instance of a hash function has state. As you write information to a hash, it sums up the data so when you call the `Sum()` method, it will give you the state of that one instance.
2. `time`: The [`time.Date`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date) function returns a `Time` struct. Why? A time is a time. It has no state. It is like an integer where you can compare them, preform maths on them, etc. The API designer decided that a modification to a time would not change the current one but make a new one. As a user of the library, if I want the time one month from now, I would want a new time object, not to change the current one I have. A time is also only 3 words in length. In other words, it is small and there would be no performance gain in using a pointer.
3. `math/big`: [big.NewInt()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt) is an interesting one. We can pretty much agree that when you modify a `big.Int`, you will often want a new one. A `big.Int` has no internal state, so why is it a pointer? The answer is simply performance. The programmers realized that big ints are … big. Constantly allocating each time you do a mathematical operation may not be practical. So, they decided to use pointers and allow the programmer to decide when to allocate new space.

Have I answered your question? Probably not. It is a design decision and you need to figure it out on a case by case basis. I use the standard library as a guide when I am designing my own libraries. It really all comes down to judgement and how you expect client code to use your types.

Comment: i had to read this a few times to realize this is a really good answer. thank you.

Comment: Great answer. I'm new to Go, and was referred here by Stephen from #go-nuts on IRC.

Answer (score 2):

Often, when you want to mimic an object-oriented style, where you have an "object" that stores state and "methods" that can alter the object, then you would have a "constructor" function that returns a pointer to a struct (think of it as the "object reference" as in other OO languages). Mutator methods would have to be methods of the pointer-to-the-struct type instead of the struct type itself, in order to change the fields of the "object", so it's convenient to have a pointer to the struct instead of a struct value itself, so that all "methods" will be in its method set.

For example, to mimic something like this in Java:

```
class Car {
  String make;
  String model;
  public Car(String myMake) { make = myMake; }
  public setMake(String newMake) { make = newMake; }
}
```

You would often see something like this in Go:

```
type Car struct {
  make string
  model string
}
func NewCar(myMake string) *Car {
  return &Car{myMake, ""}
}
func (self *Car) setMake(newMake string) {
  self.make = newMake
}
```

Comment: so, with go, should i not be using the `new` keyword? i should just return a reference as you've illustrated? i'm confused by your example.

Comment: @Carson: well, you can use `new`, but `new` initializes the value to the zero value of the type, which for structs is all fields initialized to the zero value. That might not be a validly initialized value for all types. If zero value is fine for initializing your type, then you can just use `new`; but if your type needs a custom "constructor", then you should define your own function like I showed

Answer (score 1):

Very losely, exceptions are likely to show up in specific circumstances:

- Return a value when it is really small (no more than few words).
- Return a pointer when the copying overhead would substantially hurt performance (size is a lot of words).